# Sharepoint 2010 user not found error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting this error when I try to do the following:

- accessing a library settings
- accessing a workflow settings
- accessing a list settings
- accessing a task settings

p.s.

- I'm using SharePoint 2010 on Windows Server 2008 64-bit
- I am using an Administrator account.
- I recently installed the Active Directory on the server

Regrds

Answer (score 0):

Check the workflows. Browse to the site, and Edit in SharePoint Designer. If you click on the workflows, there may be one there that was created by a user that no longer exists, or a local user that is not in AD. Save and republish each of them, and you will probably be allright. Bumped into this when our SP admin got married, and her account changed.
A long term solution would be to have a functional account that is not tied to an individual be the login that publishes all of the workflows. Each workflow runs as the user that publishes it, so any account changes can break a workflow.