# Sharepoint User Not Found while loading lists in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint

We have a winforms app which pulls all lists from Office 365 SharePoint site. Recently I started getting error "user not found". I can login to the SP site https://[name].sharepoint.com/sites/[folder1]/[userfolder]/SitePages/Home.aspx from browser and see all lists. However when I run the winforms app, it throws error.

```
MsOnlineClaimsHelper claimsHelper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper(sharePointSite, sharePointUser, sharePointPassword);
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointSite);
clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += claimsHelper.clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();    
Web web = clientContext.Web;

// Retrieve all lists from the server. 
clientContext.Load(web.Lists);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //<-- Throws error here
```

Error

```
    Message "User cannot be found." string
    ServerErrorCode -2146232832 int
    ServerErrorDetails  null    object
    ServerErrorTraceCorrelationId   "ee687f9d-c05a-2000-2113-22de7e4f8fe1"  string
    ServerErrorTypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException"  string
    ServerErrorValue    null    string
    ServerStackTrace    ""  string
```

Similar (didn't help) :  [Sharepoint 2010 user not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464905/sharepoint-2010-user-not-found-error)

I am fetching lists, not sure if this is related. :  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f9221c7b-f835-4041-ac21-ab896bae106f/microsoftsharepointspexception-user-cannot-be-found?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Help/suggestions much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried retrieving all the users from the Sharepoint site via WinForms?  It is possible the variables you are sending `MsOnlineClaimsHelper` have issues and because of that the Sharepoint query is executing but for some reason the user isn't being found.

Comment: Thanks @jaredbaszler for your reply! User could login successfully but not fetch any lists. I have tried [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c#content)  as well. I can fetch some other information like site title/other details but not list.

Answer (score 0):

Two options to fix the issue (if the first does not work try the second):

1. `User owner= web.ensureuser(domain\\username)`
2. `User owner=web.CurrentUser;`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the credentials

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("domain\\user", "password");
context.Credentials = credentials;
```